# Is there a way to use legacy admob without changing the code

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, android-keystore

Is there a way to use legacy admob without changing the code as I have lost the keystore to one of my apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've lost your keystore then you can no longer update your app in any way. Sorry!

In the past other companies have just re-released the app under a new name and then removed the other app from the store.